# How to set python3 command to work in aws linux 2?

Tags: python, rpm

I followed first approach in this [link](https://techviewleo.com/how-to-install-python-on-amazon-linux/) to install python 3.8

Steps I followed:

```
 sudo yum install -y amazon-linux-extras
 amazon-linux-extras | grep -i python
sudo amazon-linux-extras enable python3.8
sudo yum install python3.8
```

After that, python3.8 command is working.

```
[ec2-user@amazonlinux ~]$ python3.8 --version
Python 3.8.5
```

But not python3.

```
[ec2-user@amazonlinux ~]$ python3 --version
-bash: python3: command not found
```

changing the link below, is suggested not as it is breaking the system.
So I didn't try.

```
rm /usr/bin/python3 
ln -s /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use alternatives to manage different versions of python interpreters

`update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.8 1`